# AWS Quicksight: Comparing one string column against another

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Trying to build a calculated field in Quicksight so i can compare one string column against another and return a Boolean/integer if it matches, basically the equivalent of this in Power BI:

```
IF (
CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Owners Reg'[Registered Owner],'Owners Reg'[Alias_AKA.1] )
|| CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Owners Reg'[Alias_AKA.1], 'Owners Reg'[Registered Owner])
,
"Yes",
"No"
)
```

I've found the `locate` function but I'm struggling to see how i can use it. I was thinking something along the lines of

`locate({Registered Owner},{Alias_AKA.1})`

but i can't find any example of `locate` being used in the way i want to. Can anyone please help point me in the right direction as i'm a new user to AWS QS coming from Power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just need to add another function - `ifelse`

Following can be used -

```
ifelse(locate({String-1},{String-2}) > 0,'yes','no')
```

Refer sample data-set and function result below -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm still learning the syntax in Quicksight